# remainder of a sum of consecutive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone help me this problem? I know the sum of consecutive integers is n(n+1)/2, but I don't know how to move forward from here.

> If 738 consecutive integers are added together, where the 178th number in sequence is 4,256,815, what is the remainder when this sum is divided by 6?

Comment: You already had a perfectly good answer from the previous time you asked the same question. Now I have wasted my time. Sad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of any $6$ consecutive integers is 
$$ 6n+1+2+3+4+5 = 6n+15 \equiv 3 \pmod 6 $$
Since $738=123\cdot 6$ you have $123$ such groups ...